# Is a telephone number with "+" different from one without "+"?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, openurl

Is a telephone number with "+" different from one without "+"?

I mean that a number such as `A: +1(510)234-567` and `B:1510234567`. Is it the same number for the call? I want to make a call which number to get from the address book. The format is A, and after use,

```
NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"-+() *#"];
txt = [[txt componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
```

the number format is B.

Is it a good solution?

Comment: in my experience if I don't put the + on my pad while dialing abroad it simply doesn't work. the + allows the phone to make a transformation and prepend a list of numbers that makes the world call work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code may help you solve the problem! Have a try.

```
- (NSURL *)makeCall:(NSString *)number
{
    NSString *txt = number;
    NSString *cleanedString = [[txt componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789-+()"] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", cleanedString]];
    return telURL;
}

BOOL bCanCall = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]canOpenURL:urlToCall];

if (bCanCall)
{
    UIWebView *callView = [[[UIWebView alloc]init] autorelease];
    [callView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlToCall]];
    [self.view addSubview:callView];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much .Although it's late to answer my question ,but it must be useful to other guys .

Answer (score 2):

From the Wikipedia article *[Telephone numbering plan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbering_plan)*, *Country code*:

> Country code - necessary only when dialing to phones in other
>   countries. In international usage, telephone numbers are prefixed with
>   the country code preceded by a "+", and with spaces in place of
>   hyphens (e.g., "+XX YYY ZZZ ZZZZ"). This allows the reader to choose
>   which Access Code (also known as International Dialing Digit) they
>   need to dial from their location. However, it is often quoted together
>   with the international access code which must precede it in the dial
>   string, for example "011" in NANP countries (including Canada,
>   Bermuda, and the United States): "011-XX-YYY-ZZZ-ZZZZ", or "00" in
>   most European countries: "00-XX-YYY-ZZZ-ZZZZ". This can cause
>   confusion as a different Access Code may be used where the reader is
>   located. On GSM networks, "+" is an actual character that may be used
>   internally as the international access code, rather than simply being
>   a convention.

It looks like `+` is not mandatory, but it makes it clear if someone is dialing international areas.

Comment: I don't understand.For the number A:+1(510)234-567 I got from address book,I wanna use openURL make a call. I can't call another guy which number is 1510234567.is it means that +1(510)234-567 is the same as 530234567 in America.

Comment: yes in america it would work but what about other countries? as stated stated in the "confusion" part. Without the `+` would you consider `001` as country code or area code or ? As I understand better put `+<country code>` or `00<countrycode>` and then follow it by your number.